# hashchange only when not from click

Tags: jquery, hash, click

I'm using this

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', gotohash);
```

to add deep linking to my app.

My problem is that it also fires when I click an `<a>` with `href=#whatever`
and I only want to use it when the user uses the back and forward buttons of the browser or goes directly to a url with hash in it.

I'm thinking of `hashChangeEnabled=true/false` and then turn it off on every click

but is there an easier way to detect whether it's caused by click or not?

What is the best practice?

---

**My Solution**

```
var disableHashChange = false;

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
  if(!disableHashChange ){
    gotohash();
  }
  disableHashChange = false;
});

$('.link').click(function(){
  disableHashChange = true;
}
```

**Answer** by imsky

```
var lastLinkEvent;

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
  if(lastLinkEvent != window.location.hash){
    gotohash();
    lastLinkEvent = "";
  }
});

$('.link').click(function(){
    lastLinkEvent = $(this).attr('href');;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's probably better to rethink your application's flow...

Comment: Miro, in the 'Answer' section above - should the variable ***lastLinkEvent*** not be in global scope so that it would also be accessible via the 'hashchange' event? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. lastLinkEvent should be in the global scope :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hashchange event will fire when you change location, so if you don't want it to fire when links are clicked, either change the link href attribute or add a click handler that uses `preventDefault`.

Edit: Given that you want your links to work, you should set up an application variable constrained only to link events, such as `lastLinkEvent` and set it to the hash contained within its URL. Then in your processing function, check if `lastLinkEvent` is already the hash, and if it is, prevent execution.

Comment: but I DO want my url to change. I just don't want the hashchange event to fire. My click handler already does what the hashchange event does. So now it does same thing twice.

Comment: it works with the only exception that I execute when lastLinkEvent!=hash instead of preventing execution.

Comment: so basically what is happening is that lastLinkEvent is faster than the hashchange and it saying... "hey this hashchange is coming form a link. Don't fire"? Right ? :)

Comment: That's what I meant (execute when lastLinkEvent isn't the hash). About the execution order: you can guarantee correct execution order by using ``preventDefault`` and changing ``document.location`` manually. Alternatively you could change the handler to use ``mousedown`` which would make it practically impossible for ``hashchange`` to fire before the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the current target was an anchor tag or not inside of hashchange

http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: That won't work because for the onhashchange event the target will always be "window", even if the hashchange got triggered by an anchor tag.